# IOS 4.3 table view scroll aborts

Tags: ios4

I just had a quick question, I create a table view with only a couple cells of information. I wanted to leave it scrollable just for fun. when I scroll one or more cells off the screen, they are released, and then when I let go the app aborts. No real errors, but I can see using NSLog that its trying to use the indexpath for the last cell that went off screen but for whatever reason cant. Is this normal? here is most of the code.

```
NSLog(@" %@", indexPath);//this gives me
NSDictionary *types = [streams objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *title = [types objectForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"cell title is %@" , title);
[[cell textLabel] setText:title];
```

the logs give me

```
2011-06-28 16:40:11.887 json2[2942:207]  <NSIndexPath 0x5a2fd10> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2011-06-28 16:40:11.888 json2[2942:207] cell title is Website
2011-06-28 16:40:11.889 json2[2942:207]  <NSIndexPath 0x5a32120> 2 indexes [0, 1]
2011-06-28 16:40:11.889 json2[2942:207] cell title is Flash
2011-06-28 16:40:11.890 json2[2942:207]  <NSIndexPath 0x5a2f3c0> 2 indexes [0, 2]
2011-06-28 16:40:11.890 json2[2942:207] cell title is Animation
2011-06-28 16:40:18.238 json2[2942:207]  <NSIndexPath 0x5a2fd10> 2 indexes [0, 0]
```

so its obviously trying to load the data infor for 0, 0 when i release pressure, but it cant find it?

thanks, and hope this was not anywhere else, I checked and found some close but nothing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[[cell textLabel] setText:title];`
Try `cell.textLabel.text = title`

Comment: OK , I got it, took me a few days to get used to debugger. I overwrote the default getter for my array streams and retained it there. that fixed it because once I got used to debugging I could see that my streams was getting released without be saying so.